# Show a progress dialog in android tab layout

Tags: android, android-tabhost, progressdialog

I need to show a progress dialog, while clicking a tab,

My code id

```
public class SIPTabWidget extends TabActivity{
 Intent intent;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    final Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab



    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListContacts.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("contacts")
    .setIndicator("",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_contacts))
        .setContent(intent);



    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Dialer.class);
    spec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("dialer")
    .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_dial))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Favorites.class);
    spec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("favorites")
    .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_favorites))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.Settings.class);
    spec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("settings")
    .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_settings))
    .setContent(intent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

when i click the settings tab, Setting activity is called, in its oncreate i gave

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Please wait..", "Doing stuff..", true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
```

[image]

for me before showing the Settings layout its taking some time to load the layout, so before that i need to show the ProgressDialog, means the time **when i click the Settings tab** and i need to dismiss the Dialog when the tab changes to Settings

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        System.out.println(" Tab ID:  "+tabId);
if(tabId.equals("dial")){
dialog .dismiss();
}

    }
});
```

Settings.class

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, OnClickListener {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("Settings oncreate");
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Please  wait..", "Doing stuff..", true);
        handler = new Handler() {

              @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              dialog.dismiss();

              }
           };


           Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    //send message
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);      
                }
            };  





       if (Receiver.mContext == null) Receiver.mContext = this;
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        setDefaultValues();
        Codecs.check();
        t.start





    }
```

Comment: why don't you use the AsyncTask class in your setting tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well each tab is an activity... I suppose that `what is taking time` is in the settings activity...

Put this in the setting activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Please wait..", "Doing stuff..", true);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show(); 
Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    Looper.myLooper().prepare();
    //DO EVERYTHING YOU WANT!

    //Finally
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    dialog.dismis();
    }
    });
}
};
Thread T = new Thread(myRun);
T.start();
```

**Remember**: In you `run()` in this block

```
//DO EVERYTHING YOU WANT!
```

If anything needs to change the UI, you must do it using

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //DO IT
    }
    });
```

Comment: i have tried it on Settings tab, After but i need to show the progress dialog before the settings layout is displayed. here when i click the settings tab, there is delay for showing the layout, the progress dailog is give in the settings activity context,..but i need to show it inside the tabactivity context

Comment: Do you think the work that is taking time is in the `onDestroy` of the previous tab ? or is it in the `onCreate` of the settings tab?

Comment: Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){ public void run(){     //DO EVERYTHING YOU WANT! is not calling

Comment: i have a method inside the run method, but its not calling

Comment: oh sorry @jennifer I edited the answer :$ I added Thread T = new Thread(myRun); T.start();

Comment: 08-02 19:06:34.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32315): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-02 19:06:34.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32315):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121) exception is thrown

Comment: ok add `Looper.myLooper().prepare()` or `Looper.prepare()` in `//DO EVERYTHING YOU WANT! ` .. I will edit

Comment: @Sherif let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2061/discussion-between-jennifer-and-sherif)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the asyntask feature of android to show Progress dialog refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: wher i will start this Async task

Comment: on create itself, then load your layout in doinbackground() method of asyntask & on postExecute remove your Progress

Answer (score 1):

Refer to my answer here,

["Rotating wheel" progress dialog while deleting folder from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894698/rotating-wheel-progress-dialog-while-deleting-folder-from-sd-card/6894744#6894744)

or you must go for async task to do this.

Comment: i need to show the progress dialog before the settings layout is displayed. here when i click the settings tab, there is delay for showing the layout, the progress dailog is give in the settings activity context,..but i need to show it inside the tabactivity context

Comment: Try modifying it accordingly. Try calling progressdialog.show before setContent to your activity. But this has to be done as I have done it. Use separate thread.

Comment: i tries like that, an exception is thrown when i tried to close the dialog inside that handler

Comment: 08-02 19:06:34.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32315): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-02 19:06:34.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32315):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)

Comment: Have you written Progressdialog.show() inside thread? Don't use it inside the thread. Use it exactly as shown there

Answer (score 0):

If getParent() doesn't work for you, try using just `TabsActivity.context` (or substitute the name of your parent tab activity class). I am using nested activities and as a result using getParent() is still not returning the right context for the dialog.

After trying 20 different variations of the suggestions above I replaced this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

With:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabsActivity.context);
```

and it worked like a charm. You'll also need to create the context variable in the TabsActivity class. Something like `public static TabsActivity context;` and `context=this` in the onCreate method.