# Android - Unable to add window -- token is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an `AlertDialog` from different thread. I received following crash on firebase:
`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@415924 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Tried to check if the context is active or not, but the issue still persists.

```
if(!((Activity)context).isFinishing()) {
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you using `WindowManager.addView()`?

Comment: No. I'm using AlertDialog.Builder to build the dialog. Now I'm also checking if the activity is already destroyed or not before showing the dialog. Let's see if that solves the issue.

Comment: `from different thread.` Don't tell me that you're showing the dialog in a background thread?.

Comment: No. I am showing dialog in UI thread.

Comment: This might help you. [WindowManager$BadTokenException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977771/windowmanagerbadtokenexception)