# Progress Dialog not giving effect

Tags: android

I am trying to show progress dialog using this code

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(v.getRootView().getContext(), "", "Please Wait....",true,true);
                MyThread mt = new MyThread(SAVE1);
                mt.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                mt.start();
```

but I can only see the progress dialog not progress effect on it(like Rounding some Image) 
any one can help me ?

Comment: i think you need to load progress bar till data are load

Comment: refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894698/rotating-wheel-progress-dialog-while-deleting-folder-from-sd-card/6894744#6894744 (if it is of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(yourRunningActivity.this, "loading", "Please Wait....");
                MyThread mt = new MyThread(SAVE1);
                mt.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                mt.start();
```