# Get EditText from Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make and API to print tickets on zebra printers, I have my main activity(just for testing):

```
public class ZebraPrinterActivity extends Activity {
public EditText macAddress;
public Button testButton;
public Printer zebra;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    macAddress = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    testButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    zebra = new Printer(new ZebraPrinterActivity());
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}}
```

and I have my class (API) called Printer:

```
public class Printer {

private ZebraPrinterConnection zebraPrinterConnection;
private ZebraPrinter zebra;
private String MAC;

public Printer (Activity activity) {
    zebraPrinterConnection = null;
    zebra = null;
    activity....get Edit Text
    this.MAC = MAC;
}}
```

What i need is getting the edit text from the early activity, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
EditText macAddress = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String macAddressString = macAddress.getText();
```

Some operations on Views such as `EditText` may not work due to a restriction on accessing UI elements in a non-UI thread. If that occurs, see this SO question for ways to access the EditText element from another thread:

[Do some Android UI stuff in non-UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223389/do-some-android-ui-stuff-in-non-ui-thread)

Or the Android blog post on the same topic:

[Painless Threading | Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: You should be able to do that in the Printer class (see the 'activity' variable rather than 'this')

Comment: ok, you are right, but is there another way? i think this way is not the best

Comment: You are asking how to access the EditText, and this is a way to do it in one line. Another way to do it would be to pass the EditText or String directly to your API (the last of which I prefer, to be honest)

Comment: I mean like activity.getAllWidgets().getEdtText(); or something like that

Comment: The only decent way to retrieve a `View` from an activity is to use `findViewByID`. Otherwise you can create a getter method, but you'll have to pass through a ZebraPrinterActivity type rather than just an Activity. That's up to you, but I would recommend using `findViewByID`